# WSO2 App Store throws error when attempting to save a users Application against mysql

Tags: mysql, transactions, wso2

API Store is throwing errors when I try to create or edit an application

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
```

I've added the setting of

```
init-command='set autocommit=0'
```

to the my.cnf file

I've also added the flag:

```
?relaxAutoCommit=true
```

to the connection string but to no avail.  I continue to get this error.

I am using the same mysql database for both the WSO2_CARBON_DB and teh WSO2AM_DB plus I have a single publisher node and two separate store nodes all pointing to the same mysql datasource.

I notice the application edit is saved (or the new application is created) but the exception is still thrown in the console and an error message appears in the user interface (as per the error at the top of this question).

Is there some other setting, within the WSO2 conf files that I have to tweak in order to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add both `autoReconnect` and `relaxAutoCommit` flags to the jdbc url of your defined "WSO2AM_DB" datasource in `master-datasources.xml` file. This will resolve your issue.

```
<configuration>

<url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AM_DB?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true</url>

<username>xxxx</username>

<;password>xxxxx</password>
```

EDIT: I updated the url to reflect the correct syntax for escaping the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

just for the sake of completeness, the JDBC URL shoud be

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WSO2CARBON_DB?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true