# WSO2 API Manager 'Can't call commit when autocommit=true'

Tags: wso2

The WSO2 API Manager is raising the following error when adding an API:

```
[2013-08-08 16:39:00,062] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Error while adding the API: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.model.APIIdentifier@81588b20 to the database
java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
```

I am currently using MySQL as database. How do I fix this?

Comment: The solution is the same as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476915/wso2-app-store-throws-error-when-attempting-to-save-a-users-application-against.

Comment: Great. Could you please answer the question here. So that this question will not come under unanswered category. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'relaxAutoCommit=true' parameter to the datasources in wso2am-1.8.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml should fix this issue.